A problem with this function that return table in SQL Server
I created this function and it is not working:
CREATE FUNCTION MisionsOfUser
    (@UserName NVARCHAR(20),
     @Password NVARCHAR(10))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT dbo.RecognizeUserID(@UserName, @Password)) = 1
        RETURN (SELECT * 
                FROM dbo.Tasks t 
                JOIN Users u ON t.UserDoing = u.userID 
                WHERE @UserName = userName)
    RETURN (SELECT -1);
END

I expected to see the details of the user in a table.
Instead, I get these errors:

Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure MisionsOfUser, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 262]
A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure MisionsOfUser, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 262]
A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure MisionsOfUser, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 262]
Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'


RETURNS TABLE means it's an inline (single statement) Table Valued Function. The docs are quite clear on what can and cannot be used in different types of functions.
You can't use BEGIN END and control flow unless you use a Multi-Statement TVF (which you shouldn't use as it's bad performance-wise). Even then, you can't return a single scalar value, you would need to insert into a table variable.
Honestly I'm not clear why you need to return -1 anyway. Just don't return any rows.
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION MisionsOfUser
(@UserName NVARCHAR(20), @Password NVARCHAR(10))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Tasks t
    JOIN Users u ON t.UserDoing = u.userID
    WHERE @UserName = userName
      AND dbo.RecognizeUserID(@UserName, @Password) = 1
;

I can't see what dbo.RecognizeUserID does, but scalar functions are slow, you could probably inline this here as well.

I hope I don't need to tell you not to store plain-text passwords. And nvarchar(10) is wholely inappropriate: it's too short, and if you are using hashing as you should then it should be varbinary.

Thanks for mention that! I'm just a student, and it is not a real database, so I'm not worry about it.

Best practice and industry standards needs to start from the beginning. Otherwise you'll still be doing bad things on real databases.
